# Using user data to calculate formulas in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-breeze

I am currently trying to find a way to use the data that is already on the users table to calculate the BMI of the user.

Many of the tutorials I see, they have a form, and a post, but what do I do if I already have the weight and height of the user?

I have tried building a controller like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class IMCController extends Controller
{
    public function calculate(){


        $weight = Auth::user()->weight;
        $height = Auth::user()->height;

        $imc = $weight / ($height^2);


        return $imc;

    }
 
}
```

But when I call it on the view it says the class doesn't exist.

Comment: Try `{{ (new \App\Http\Controllers\IMCController())->calculate() }}`

Comment: Make BMI a property/method of `User`, instead of adding an outlandish `Controller`.

Comment: Nitpicking here, but a Controller method should return a `view()` or `response()`; if you want to call another Controller method, it should be an AJAX request, not a direct call as suggested above.

Comment: share full error message here explaining which class doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line before the Class definition

```
   use Auth;
```

Get your current user height & weight using the following code:

```
      $weight = Auth::user()->weight;
      $height = Auth::user()->height;
```